# How to modify the default ticket create mask in OTRS?

Tags: otrs

currently I am setting up a new instance of the Open Ticket Request System.

I wanted to know if it is possible to remove the *To customer user:*  field in the ticket create mask, since we are not needing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit silly to be the default config IMO.

You can set a default and remove the requirement to pick a queue in
Sysconfig > ticket > Frontend::Customer::Ticket::ViewNew

Edit both of the following :
Ticket::Frontend::CustomerTicketMessage###QueueDefault - set it to your desired queue

Ticket::Frontend::CustomerTicketMessage###Queue - set it to No

Comment: not relevant anymore, but thank you